# HTML Video not being responsive

Tags: html, video, tags

I have been fiddling with a video background, and as a header, for awhile now, and my video will not adjust to the window size in a responsive manner. It is staying a fixed height/width, and when I change my CSS to conform using %'s, it disappears. To note: I have an image above/placed on the video background.

```
<!--Header-->
<div id="video-container">
  <video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" type="video/mp4" src="assets/header.mp4" loop></video>
  <img class="headerimg" src="assets/hotel 1.png" alt="" height="500" width="500"></img>
  <a href="#welcome"><img class="dropdown" src="assets/dropdown.png" alt="" height="25" width="25"></img></a>
</div>

#video-container {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#video-container video {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: -1
}

.headerimg {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 27%;
 height: auto;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
 -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox < 16 */
 -ms-animation: fadein 5s; /* Internet Explorer */
 -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
 animation: fadein 5s;
 }
```

Any help is welcome. I am quite a beginner at web development, so please don't be too harsh. Every step is a learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

I would use vw instead of % or px!

It‘s way more responsive! Unless ofc you want something fixed. Then you should use px.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I applied this, and now all of my content below doesn't conform correctly. Meaning, I get a giant gap that increases when the viewport changes.